# How to pass variable in <a href> url link - Ionic to open external page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I need to call a php page from Ionic. In `home.html` I am calling a url as shown below -

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.example.com?">pdf</a>
```

How do I add a variable from `home.ts` and make it

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3schools.com?ADAM">pdf</a>
```

In `home.ts` I have a variable `name = "ADAM";`.  How do I join this on home.html side inside `<a href>` tag ?

Answer (score 2):

Define variable in home.ts
i.e.

```
var url="https://www.w3schools.com?name=ADAM"
```

and then you can access it from html like

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{url}}">pdf</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using queryparam

```
<a [routerLink] = "your url" [queryParams] = "{ m : [selectedMonth.id] }" queryParamsHandling="merge">
  Test                              
</a>
```